# Specify the type returned from FileReader readAsDataURL() as PNG and not TIFF?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm getting an image that has been pasted into the content editable div and during paste the `types` in listed in the `Clipboard` include "`image/png`" and "`image/tiff`".

When I get that image using a `FileReader` and `readAsDataURL` the `base64` image string it returns is a `TIFF`, "`data:image/tiff,`".

Is there a way to specify to the `FileReader` to return a `PNG`,  "`data:image/png`"?

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481795/how-to-convert-a-image-src-from-a-blob-string-to-data-uri/).

Comment: From where this image has been copied into clipboard? What browser gives you both tiff and png, and moreover, on which OS. And to only answer your question, a FileReader only reads the Blob you pass to it, it won't analyze the data, so your problem lies before you even convert it to a dataURI (for I still don't see what reasons btw).

Comment: This is on Safari on OSX

Comment: Ok, and from where the image has been copied to clipboard? Almost every applications will copy different data in such case. But you can see in "Finder > Edit > Show Clipboard" that osX prefers raw image data to be encapsulated in a tiff.

Comment: I use CMD + SHIFT + 4, then draw a selection and then hold down CTRL. This copies the selection to the clipboard. I've checked Finder clipboard and it says it's a PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.
`FileReader.readAsDataURL()` only converts the binary data held in the passed Blob to a base64 string, it doesn't do any other conversion.
It will only prepend the corresponding MIME header to whatever it thinks this data is (this check is first done against the Blob's `type`, and then probably against magic-numbers), but you can't force it to convert the data to something else.

```js
const fr = new FileReader();
const fakeGif = new Blob(['foo'], {type:'image/gif'});
fr.onload = onload;
fr.readAsDataURL(fakeGif);

function onload(){
  console.log(fr.result); // with image/gif MIME
  console.log(atob(fr.result.split(',')[1])) // still just "foo"...
}
```

---

Now to your case, since Safari still doesn't support the [DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem) interface, you are out of luck.

Even though *Grab* utility does save a png File in the clipboard, Safari chose to display the tiff raw data.

You can check this assertion in your dev's Network panel, where you will see that the image is fetched as image/tiff.

Browsers that do support DataTransferItem interface can retrieve the png file attached in the clipboard though, so let's hope Safari implement this interface soon enough.

So one way to convert this TIFF image to a png one, is to go through a canvas element:

```js
// an Array to hold pasted Files
var files = [];

// We start by checking if the browser supports the 
// DataTransferItem interface. If not, we need to create a 
// contenteditable element that catches all pasted data 
if (!window.DataTransferItem) {
  var pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
  pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");

  // We can hide the element and append it to the body,
  pasteCatcher.style.opacity = 0.5;
  document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);

  // as long as we make sure it is always in focus
  pasteCatcher.focus();
  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    pasteCatcher.focus();
  });
}
// Add the paste event listener
window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);

/* Handle paste events */

function pasteHandler(e) {
  // We need to check if event.clipboardData is supported (Chrome)
  if (e.clipboardData) {
    // Get the items from the clipboard
    var items = e.clipboardData.items || e.clipboardData.files;
    itemcount = items.length;
    if (itemcount) {
      // Loop through all items, looking for any kind of image
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        getItem(items[i]);
      }
    } else {
      // This is a cheap trick to make sure we read the data
      // AFTER it has been inserted.
      setTimeout(checkInput, 1);
    }
    // If we can't handle clipboard data directly (Firefox), 
    // we need to read what was pasted from the contenteditable element
  } else {

    console.log("checking input");

    // This is a cheap trick to make sure we read the data
    // AFTER it has been inserted.
    setTimeout(checkInput, 1);
  }
}
/* For browsers that support DataTransferItem interface */
function getItem(item)  {
  if (item.type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
    // We need to represent the image as a file,
    var blob = item instanceof Blob ? item : item.getAsFile();
    // save the File for later use if needed
    files.push(blob);
    // and use a URL or webkitURL (whichever is available to the browser)
    // to create a temporary URL to the object
    var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
    // The URL can then be used as the source of an image
    createImage(source);
  }
}
/* For older browsers */
/* Parse the input in the paste catcher element */
function checkInput() {

  // Store the pasted content in a variable
  var child = pasteCatcher.childNodes[0];

  if (child) {
    // If the user pastes an image, the src attribute
    // will represent the image as a base64 encoded string.
    if (child.tagName === "IMG") {
      getPngFromIMG(child, function(blob) {
        // Clear the inner html to make sure we're always
        // getting the latest inserted content
        pasteCatcher.innerHTML = "";
        // save the png blob in our list
        files.push(blob);
        createImage(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      });
    }
  }
}

function getPngFromIMG(img, callback) {
  if (img.naturalWidth) // if already loaded
    draw();
  else
    img.onload = draw;

  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(callback);
  }
}
/* Creates a new image from a given source */
function createImage(source) {
  var pastedImage = new Image();
  pastedImage.onload = function(e) {
    loadImage.src = e.target.src;
  }
  pastedImage.src = source;
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log(files);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="pasteArea" placeholder="Paste Image Here"></textarea>
<img id="loadImage" />
<button id="btn">do something with pasted files</button>
```

Comment: So no way to get base 64 png/jpeg... :(

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Yes you could. IIRC tiff is just a container holding raw data, which might not be to hard to parse, so you could instead get the arrayBuffer of this blob and then convert it to png or jpeg yourself (I guess some libs already do that out there), or if you don't care about losing quality, you could also probably draw it to a canvas which will give you the ability to export as png or jpeg. (I never tried to draw a tiff on canvas on safari though)

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I added an updated code that does convert the image data to a png Blob for Safari. It also store all the Blob in an array so that you can do whatever you want later on with these Blobs. And I also updated your logic, since no browser does have a `window.Clipboard` object, I am not sure what you were trying to get there, so I changed it to `window.DataTransferItem`, which is the current culprit in different up to date browsers.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up more than once. The code was from another answer that I was updating as I was working through it.

Comment: For informational purposes, if you want to get the `dataURI` value from the canvas you can use `var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` after  `canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts thanks for the edit, does Safari sometime sets this image's width and height properties itself?

Comment: I don't think so. When I was testing it I thought what if the user selects multiple elements. So I was pasting in different content (image/png, text/html (text and images) and in one case the image had it's width and height set to a different value than it's actual width and height (max width and height at 100%). Since I was immediately displaying the image data in another image I noticed the content was clipped.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts ok, good to know. Anyway, I don't think this behavior is very well documented in the specs, so it's rather up to the browsers to implement it as they wish, and thus, it's better to use naturalWidth & naturalHeight, so thanks again for the edit.